# Rails how to add images from folder to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, haml

I'am new to ruby on rails. I already import all the countries in csv file. Now, I want to add my own design images for each country. What is the easiest way to add the images for each country? is it I need use model or controller to add it? Thanks

Comment: You should explore file attachment gems like carrierwave, paperclip, dragon fly, and then you could loop through your folder to attache them and store them

Comment: Do you want to add these images through the UI as a user would, or do you just want to render images that you are storing in your code base?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a model call `country.rb` and it looks like

```
create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       default: "", null: false
    t.string   "image",      default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

you can now use a gem called '[carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)'

then run

`rails generate uploader Image`

in your model

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I hope this was helpful